# What does the node element of webpack's config file do?

Tags: node.js, webpack

Some `webpack.config.js` files contain this:

```
node: {
    global: true,
    crypto: 'empty',
    process: true,
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
}
```

What exactly does this do? [The docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node) don't really have much to say about it:

> Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff